# Fine Tuning Pretrained Model MobileNet_V2 in Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, classification, pytorch, pre-trained-model, mobilenet

I am new to pyTorch and I am trying to Create a Classifier where I have around 10 kinds of Images Folder Dataset, for this task I am using Pretrained model( MobileNet_v2 ) but the problem is I am not able to change the FC layer of it. There is not model.fc attribute.
Can anyone help me to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Do something like below:

```
import torch
model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision', 'mobilenet_v2', pretrained=True)
print(model.classifier)

model.classifier[1] = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=model.classifier[1].in_features, out_features=10)
print(model.classifier)
```

output:

```
Sequential(
  (0): Dropout(p=0.2)
  (1): Linear(in_features=1280, out_features=1000, bias=True)
)
Sequential(
  (0): Dropout(p=0.2)
  (1): Linear(in_features=1280, out_features=10, bias=True)
)
```

**Note**: you would need `torch >= 1.1.0` to use `torch.hub`.

Answer (score 8):

From the [MobileNet V2 source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/models/mobilenet.html#mobilenet_v2) it looks like this model has a sequential model called classifier in the end. Therefore, you should be able to change the final layer of the classifier like this:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.models as models
model = models.mobilenet_v2()
model.classifier[1] = nn.Linear(model.last_channel, 10)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot test this code right now.
[This](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html) is also a good reference, on how to finetune models.

Comment: Actually, module `torchvision.models` has no attribute `mobilnet_v2`. Present models are `[resnet, alexnet, vgg, squeezenet, densenet, inception]`

Comment: @AnubhavSingh, actually it does since a recent torchvision update. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html

Comment: Oh I see. My bad. Thank you so much .

Answer (score 3):

MobilenetV2 implementation asks for `num_classes` (default=1000) as input and provides `self.classifier` as an attribute which is a torch.nn.Linear layer with output dimension of `num_classes`. You can use this attribute for your fine-tuning. You can have a look at the [code](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torchvision/models/mobilenet.html) yourself for better understanding.

```py
import torchvision.models as models
model = models.mobilnet_v2(num_classes=10)
```

Comment: It's good to know there are these extra parameters! But it should be pointed out that using the `num_classes` parameter prevents from downloading the *pre-trained* model which is pretty much what this question is about. Also, [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/models/mobilenet.html#mobilenet_v2) is an updated link to the code.

Answer (score 0):

By looking into the last layer in `models.mobilenet_v2`, you can see the following:

```
(classifier): Sequential(
(0): Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=False)
(1): Linear(in_features=1280, out_features=1000, bias=True)
```

To edit the `out_features` from `1000` to any number of classes `num_classes`:

```
from torchvision import models
import torch.nn as nn
model_ft = models.mobilenet_v2(pretrained=True)
num_ftrs = model_ft.classifier[1].in_features
model_ft.classifier[1] = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes)
```